# td background image is not displaying in print preview

Tags: html, css

I have gone through several questions that has been asked regarding the same topic in Stack Overflow but couldn't find proper solution.

For eg. this is my HTML:

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">    
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center;background: url(../image/background_top2.jpg) repeat-x;width: 10%;"></td>
     <td style="width: 10px;width: 2%;"></td>
     <td style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0px;width: 10%;font-size: 18px;color:#018bb4;font-weight: bold;">
     INVOICE #
     </td>
     <td style="font-size: 15px;width:36%;text-align: left;font-weight: bold;">123</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is my CSS that has been used to print background images. I am sucessfully displaying body background images in print preview also but getting failed to display background images for table td.

```css
@media print {
   body  {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}

.vendorListHeading th td {
   background-color: #1a4567 !important;
   color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine see attached image

Please check your image path i think your image path is wrong.

[image: See Image]

Comment: Actually It is displaying in chrome. I was actually using opera hence it was not displaying . So instead of using background property I am usnig img tag , so it is displaying now in opera too.